# How to make an object disappear in Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I have used the following code to show an HTML page in my App which is supported by Action Script 3.0 and Adobe Air.

```
imports
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.LocationChangeEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//setup variables
var _stageWebView:StageWebView;
var myAdvertURL:String = "http://letschant.890m.com/v25.html";

// check that _stageWebView doesn't exist
if (!_stageWebView)
{
    _stageWebView = new StageWebView() ;
    // set the size of the html 'window'
    _stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, 480, 688);
    // add a listener for when the content of the StageWebView changes
    _stageWebView.loadURL(myAdvertURL);
}
// show the ad by setting it's stage property;
_stageWebView.stage = stage;
```

So, If I click a button all these should disappear.
I know that we should use visible:false, but where should i put the code?, This aint a movie clip, so how should I do this?

Please help.
Thank you :D

Comment: You say : "If I click a button ...", so you should execute the code, which will hide these elements, when the button is clicked.

Comment: @akmozo 
Well, how do I do this? What code should be written? A Mouse click event, and the visible=false. but this doesnt have an instance name.

P.S Sorry, if I sound soooo dumb, I am 11 year old struggling with flash :(.
I tried:
stage.visible=false
and it didnt work...

Comment: Firstly, you want to hide or remove items ? And what do you want to "hide" exactly ?

Comment: Hide, not remove. I want to hide stageWebView because once i open the frame in which the stageWebView is present, and then I go to some other frame, i can still see the website which is open in stageWebView...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StageWebView` is not a `DisplayObject`. So you cannot set its `visible` property. You'll have to use another API call to hide the web view. Setting the `viewPort` to an rectangle of 0 pixels width and height would do the job.

Addressing your immediate problem, place your button on the stage and give it the instance name `btnToggle`. Add the following code in the same frame where you've added your current chunk.

```
this.btnToggle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    _stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
});
```